# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

I am trying to use react hooks (this is my first time) but I get this error when using useEffect like the above componentDidMount: 'React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will change when *any* prop
changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props inside useEffect'

I'm trying to make a GET request to an API, and that needs some props in the url. This is my code:

```js
function SomeComponent(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        let response = await Axios.get( `/some-url/${props.obj.id}/abc`,
          
        );
        let { data } = response.data;
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
        props.totalStats({data });
      } catch (error) {
        setErrors(error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I've been looking and tried these solutions, but they don't work for me:

```js
const { id } = props.obj.id;
const {totalStats} = props.totalStats

useEffect(()=>{
//Here is the code
//I replace the $ {props.obj.id} by the id and the function props.totalStats by //totalStats
},[id,totalStats]
```

Doing it that way I obtained an undefined in the id and in the call to the function.

Then I tried doing it this way:

```js
useEffect(()=>{
//here is the code like the first one

},[props])
```

But this makes n number of requests to the api

Comment: I don't think you need to put props in the dependency array...

Comment: Yes, but that's what I was doing in the first code and I get this:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will change when *any* prop 
changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props inside useEffect

Comment: Maybe this might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook

Comment: Yes, that helped me and after doing that I got that error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the braces from the constant imports.

So it should look something like this:

```
function SomeComponent(props) {
  const objId = props.obj.id;
  const totalStats = props.totalStats;
  
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        let response = await Axios.get( `/some-url/${objId}/abc`,
          
        );
        let { data } = response.data;
        setData(data);
        setLoading(false);
        totalStats({data });
      } catch (error) {
        setErrors(error);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [objId, totalStats]);
}
```

Comment: Please describe what you did so that the OP and others can see what caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is accepted already but just to clarify why OP's solution didn't work in the begining is not about assigning consts. It is because OP made a mistake to destructure the properties. Correct way to do it:

```js
const { id } = props.obj;
const {totalStats} = props
```

Notice that I didn't put `props.object.id` or `props.totalStats`. Because if you put these you are actually trying to destructure `id` from `props.object.id` object. And `totalStats` from `props.totalStats`. Which there weren't such properties so OP got the undefined error.

You can also assign a constant from the props object as the accepted answer's way. This is practically the same thing.